# Approximation of a function by double indexed sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question in general terms. I consider three metric spaces of functions $A\subset B\subset C$, with a norm $|.|$ on $C$. I wish to prove that a certain function $f\in C$ is inside the closure of $A$ under $|.|$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose I can prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f-f_n|=0$ for some sequence of functions $f_n$ in $B$, i.e.,
$$\exists N\quad\forall n\geq N\quad |f_n-f|<\epsilon/3\qquad (i)$$

Suppose I also have, for every $n$, $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}|f_n-f_{n,k}|=0$ for some sequence of functions $f_{n,k}$ in $A$,.i.e.:
$$\exists K(n)\quad\forall k\geq K(n)\quad |f_{n,k}-f_n|<\epsilon/3\qquad (ii)$$

Am I then done?

It is not so clear to me because what I obtain is $\lim\limits_{k,n\rightarrow\infty}|f-f_{n,k}|=0$ while I would expect something like $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f-u_{n}|=0$ for some sequence in $u_n$ in $A$. To be clear: I don't want a double index, do I?

If I try to put $u_n:=f_{n,n}$ and claim that $u_n$ is a the sequence I am looking for, then I try to justify it like this, for $k\geq K(N)$:
$$ |f-f_{k,k}|\leq |f-f_N|+|f_N-f_{N,k}|+|f_{N,k}-f_{k,k}|$$
I can use (i) and (ii) to estimate the 2 first quantities but I can't estimate $|f_{N,k}-f_{k,k}|$, can I?

There might be an obvious solution...?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the bound $K(n)$ slightly to indicate dependence on $\epsilon$ as following: for each $n$ there exists a sequence of functions $f_{n,k}$ in $A$ such that for each $\epsilon>0$,

$\exists K(n,\epsilon) \quad \forall k\ge K(n) \quad |f_{n,k}-f_n|<\epsilon/3$

Now define $u_n=f_{n,K(n,|f_n-f|)}$. Let $N$ be as defined in $(i)$. Then,

$\forall n\ge N \quad |u_n-f|\le|u_n-f_n|+|f_n-f| \\ \quad \equiv |f_{n,K(n,|f_n-f|)}-f_n|+|f_n-f| \\ \quad <|f_n-f|+|f_n-f| \quad \text{(from definition of } K(n,\epsilon)\text{)}\\ \quad =2|f_n-f| \\ \quad < 2\epsilon/3 \quad \text{(from } (i) \text{)}\\ \quad <\epsilon.$